# Example of use of unregistered, dynamically created gen_server's?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

Tutorials are abound for working with gen_servers that are named in an OTP application. However, I've been unable to find a good example of dynamically spawning servers that are not registered (not named). Can someone point to a good, simple example? Not ejabberd, for example, where there is a lot to confuse the core idea I'm trying to get at.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some dynamic spawning of workers in a supervision tree going on in http://github.com/noss/iserve. The iserve application has a master registered process that i call `iserve_master` it is supervised together with a simple one for one mode supervisor.

The `iserve_master` is for asking iserve to start a http server. It can have multiple iservers, as long as they bind to unique addresses. The started servers construct a name for themself though, but that is to simplify debugging, it generates an atom using the port name.

A server is is an "eternal" loop waiting for a `iserve_socket` to call back about having accepted a connection. It starts the first one in init.

The started socket is not under supervision because it is not able to restart without losing the http socket connection anyway. And I see it as a bit of a feature to not care. Fire and forget.

Its far from perfect, but an architecture that I somewhat like.

Answer (score 2):

the simplest example would be: 
leave out the first argument {local,name} in *gen_server:start*: 
i.e. assuming your module is called **mod**:

```
start(ArgX) ->
    gen_server:start(mod, [ArgX], []).
```

then you do:

```
> {ok, Pid} = gen_server:start(mod, [66], []).
```

and the gen_server is up and running.
each call to this function spawns a new unnamed gen_server process.
note that this example is using **start** (and not **start_link**) for stand-alone use (outside of a supervisor context).

Answer (score 0):

The [rabbitmq-shovel plugin](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-shovel/) appears to have an example of this - see rabbit_shovel_sup.erl and rabbit_shovel_worker.erl.  It spawns worker gen_server processes based on settings in a configuration file.